# Ubuntu won't shutdown using integrated GPU (Vaio VPCSB)

Tags: 12.04, laptop, shutdown, vaio, hybrid-graphics

I have a Sony Vaio VPCSB1D7E (W7 + Ubuntu 12.04). It has hybrid graphics (AMD+Intel). I installed both the AMD Catalyst drivers and the Intel ones. So far, using both graphic cards works fine, but I have a problem when using the Intel card.

I cannot properly shutdown my laptop when I select the Intel card. It actually works well when using it. Then, when I shutdown the laptop, the console appears showing the shutdown process and stops in the line "shutdown laptop mode". Then, I have to long-press the shutdown button to switch off the laptop.

This only happens when using Intel's card, not AMD. Please let me know what appropriate logs would be useful to try to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: been having a similar problem. any luck?

Comment: Hi. Seems to be solved with the latest kernel version. Not a clue about why it happened before but it seems fixed so far.

Comment: Thanks Raul. Can you give me a few more details? Do you mean a kernel update for 12.04 or are you now on 13.04? I'm sticking to 12.04 for the meanwhile but have to do the 10s force poweroff whenever I set catalyst to use the Intel GPU which I use most of the time.

Comment: Upgrading to Catalyst 13.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 solved my shutdown problems.